# How to select all nodes using xmllint where node on same level has certain value?

Tags: xpath, xmllint

Consider the following `example.xml` file

```
<all>
  <item>
    <name>foo</name>
    <value>5</value>
    <readonly>true</readonly>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>boo</name>
    <value>2</value>
    <readonly>false</readonly>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>bar</name>
    <value>9</value>
    <readonly>true</readonly>
  </item>
</all>
```

I would like to list `foo` and `bar` because they are `readonly` items. This didn't work out for me:

```
cat example.xml | xmllint --xpath "all/item[readonly/text() = "true"]/name" -
```

I received:

```
XPath set is empty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this xpath :

```
/all/item[readonly='true']/name
```

Your initial xpath also looks good given the XML posted in question as input, only you may need to change double quotes with single quotes in the xpath parameter value :

```
--xpath "all/item[readonly/text() = 'true']/name"
```